# Blend Sample Data not shown

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, blend

I'm following tutorial and noticed that Sample Data doesn't work in VS 2015 Blend as in 2013 Blend. In tutorial and probably all guides by Microsoft all they say is to drag-n-drop sample data collection on ListBox and data magically is there rendered, however for me that doesn't work, nothing changes visually. In properties there is ItemSource changed to sample data one, but that's pretty much it.
[image: Blend]

Here's my sample data

[image]

And here's current result of it

[image]

Full XAML of page

```
<Page
x:Class="TutorialApp.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:TutorialApp"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource CarData}}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" >
        <TextBlock Text="Car Voter" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="OverView" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" />
    </StackPanel>
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" SelectedIndex="-1" Background="#00FFFFFB" DataContext="{StaticResource CarData}"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Which tutorial is it you're tying to follow?  I've tried for a couple of hours tonight to get design time sample data working to populate a listview in Blend 2015 without success